# Код asi(dll) библиотеки на c++ выполняется перед инициализацией приложения

Tags: c++, dll

У меня есть dll библиотека которая просто в бесконечном цикле проверяет нажата ли клавиша G; Если она нажата, то по адресу 0x9386F4 записывается значение 7000; Но проблема в том, что код этой dll выполняется перед инициализацией игры, что не даёт игре даже запуститься, потому что она ждёт окончания этого кода; Я слышал много разных ответов; В основном это было "Создать новый поток для функции в которой будет весь нужный код", либо же "ставить хук на адрес"(последнее я вообще не понял); Я пытался создать новый поток и закинуть в него void со всем кодом библиотеки, но результата было всегда всего два: либо игра не запускается (ну как бы она запустилась, отображается в Диспетчере, но она в бесконечном цикле ожидает окончания кода, который не должен заканчиваться), либо же игра нормально запускается, но функционал библиотеки не работает совсем. Может я не так что то делаю? Подскажите пожралуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от места где ты начинаешь слушать кнопку если в DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH то естественно оно запускается при запуске приложения до main, так как библиотеки имеют приоритет загрузки.

Если тебе нужен какой-то определенный момент, то нечего не мешает в attach поставить хук и читать Windows messages, и дождаться нужного момента.